# Boot loader icon uses incorrect theme

Tags: refind

I'm dual booting Elementary OS and Microsoft's Windows. Using the refind boot manager.

My Elementary OS icon uses the default theme's icon + sizing instead of whatever theme I set in refind.conf. Everything else about the theme seems to work fine (including the Windows icon). Any idea what might be causing this?

I've tried three different themes, all containing `icons/elementary_os.png`, and the Elementary OS icon doesn't work on any of them.

[image: minimal-dark]

The above image should be using [this](https://github.com/PillTime/rEFInd-minimal-dark/blob/master/theme/icons/os_elementary.png) icon.

[refind http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)  version: 0.10.5

Comment: Is this the boot loader? What boot loader is it?

Comment: Yeah. [Refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I am having the same issue

Comment: @jonnie I didn't. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files `/.VolumeIcon.icns` and `/.VolumeIcon.png` on the partition with elementary OS are overwriting the theme icon. You need to rename or remove those files to get it working.